# I installed Ruby on Rails on Windows10 but WSL doesn't see installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have already installed ruby, rails ,yarn ,node on windows 10 and it can see if i write `rails -v` or `ruby-v`  i can create projects etc basiccaly i can use ruby on rails. but in WSL Ubuntu `rails -v` returns `ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory` error WSL doesn't see ruby and rails installation on Windows10 how can i fix that?

Comment: Thats not what you want to do at all - your WSL linux will most likely not be able to use gems installed for windows. What you want to do is install a ruby version manager in Ubuntu and then handle installing rubies and gems (through bundler) all in Ubunto. I would recommend installing linuxbrew also as a compliment for apt-get.

Comment: While you might be able to get WSL to use the windows Node.js its most likely going to be a PITA vs just installing it in ubunto via apt-get or linuxbrew.

Comment: (*Don't be greedy and don't use more than you need.*) ;) It's more interesting to install the windows version and use it under WSL. That can certainly be done, but you obviously need to add your installation path to the `PATH` variable. You also need to extract the embedded ruby script from the `irb` file (bat). [There are 2!] Then you can run it with `ruby.exe -x irb.rb`. Probably need to do something similar for the gem scripts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install it all on WSL, I recommend you to follow the GoRails guide to install Ruby & RoR on windows 10

[The Guide](https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10)